# Drupal commerce and views

Tags: drupal-7, view, commerce

I recently made security updates of the core and all modules on my drupal website. All went good except when I update views from `7.x-3.7` to `7.x-3.8`. When my shopping cart is empty the page shows up with an empty table and saying "no products" but when I have products in my shopping cart it is a white page. I enabled error display and I get this : ->

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::render() in /sites/all/modules/contrib/views/plugins/views_plugin_display.inc on line 2611 Call Stack: 0.0001 128484 
1. {main}() /index.php:0 0.0744 6179152 
2. menu_execute_active_handler() /index.php:21 0.0745 6180024 
3. call_user_func_array() /includes/menu.inc:517 0.0745 6180172 
4. commerce_cart_view() /includes/menu.inc:517 0.0761 6330872 
5. commerce_embed_view() /sites/all/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/cart/includes/commerce_cart.pages.inc:48 0.1186 8104564 
6. view->render() /sites/all/modules/contrib/commerce/commerce.module:373 0.1192 8125280 
7. views_plugin_display->render() /sites/all/modules/contrib/views/includes/view.inc:1264 0.1193 8126480 
8. theme() /sites/all/modules/contrib/views/plugins/views_plugin_display.inc:2605 0.1195 8130404 
9. template_preprocess_views_view()/includes/theme.inc:1125 0.1239 8220716 
10. views_plugin_display->render_area() /sites/all/modules/contrib/views/theme/theme.inc:73
```

Where should I search and what can cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in a custom code. A hook_views_preprocess. Something changes from the 7.x-3.7 to the 7.x-3.8 so I had to correct it. Hope this will help other users

Comment: Can you please explain it better, your solution. which file/Code and where to make changes.